# advice/suggestions on javascript parsing

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a mechanism that will take a fairly small snippet of javascript containing synchronous function calls and rewrite it as asynchronous javascript.

So, for example, if I have a snippet

```
someSyncFunction();
console.log("function complete")
```

I need it reformatting to

```
someAsyncFunction(function () {console.log("function complete")} );
```

Is this a task I could take on with regex, or would I need to write a parser? If the latter, any suggestions on any libs that will assist?

Just to complicate things slightly, I also need to deal with recursion/nesting, eg...

```
someSyncFunction();
console.log("first function complete");
someSyncFunction();
console.log("second function complete");
...
```

Comment: How much javascript do you need to change? I would recommend doing this manually if possible, because I think parsing /or using regexps is likely to be fraught with complications.

Comment: the snippets will be up to 10 lines or so, and not include any function definitions.

Comment: I'm assuming you have different sync functions? and that each snippet is distinct from the rest?  I'm a bit of a dinosaur, so I'd probably stick to using find-and-replace in a decent text editor, together with manual tidying-up..

Comment: perhaps I didn't explain, but these are user-entered snippets, so I need an automatic "converter"

Comment: Easy enough to do by parsing with esprima and rewriting. Or you could look at sweet.js, a macro pre-processor.

Comment: @pinoyyid you mean this http://regex101.com/r/vW2pQ7/10 ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj that's pretty close, but isn't dealing with the recursion correctly. The second call to somSyncFunction should only be executed after the first someSyncFunction completes, so needs to be nested within the first function callback

Comment: @pinoyyid: to be clear, javascript regex can't deal with an undefined level of nesting.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte thx. i do realise that, so I was thinking that a regex based solution would need to process a single function, and then be called recursively until there were no more changes

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will need to use a parser. Regex isn't really capable of parsing arbitrarily nested javascript code. You probably will want to use http://esprima.org/ which gives you a syntax tree, in which you can locate your async functions and transform the tree appropriately.

However, I don't think you will want to re-invent the wheel. Have a look at this [list of tools that compile synchronous to asynchronous JavaScript](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS#synchronous-to-asynchronous-javascript-compilers-cps).

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the suggestions. Here are the results...

- esprima will certainly do the job, and that's where I'll go next if regex hits the buffers
- I looked at the useful list of compilers at https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS#synchronous-to-asynchronous-javascript-compilers-cps, but they all carried to much baggage for what i want to achieve. Kal came closest
- Starting with @Avinash's proposal, I found that the regex to do what I want is remarkably simple, so that's what I'll go with. To clarify, the regex at http://regex101.com/r/dL0uQ2/1 will process a single instance of a sync-> async conversion, so I'll call it recursively until  the output is stable.